# React in Typescript: Progress continues to infinity in timer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Building a racing app and I need to create a simple alert when the winner reaches the finish line (100). I am getting an infinite running race (you'll see it if you `console.log` anything in `timer`). How can I alert the winner and end race? I am only using one racer here. Another Race component handles the racers.

```js
import * as React from 'react';

interface Props {
    color: string;
    avatar: string;
}

interface State {
    interval: number;
    progress: number;
}

export class Jockey extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State;
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          interval: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
          progress: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval);
    }

    timer = () => {
        this.setState({ progress: this.state.progress + 1 });
        console.log('anyhting');
        // race doesnt stop even when progress bar hits 100.
        if (this.state.progress === 100) {
            alert('you won!!');

        }
        
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
        (this.state.progress >= 99) ? this.setState({ progress: 100 }) : '' ;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App-lane">
                    <img src={this.props.avatar} alt=""/>
                    <progress value={this.state.progress} color="red" max="100" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the interval id returned by `setInterval`, and then later use it to call `clearInterval` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)).

```
componentDidMount() {
    // store interval id so that we can clear the interval later
    this.timerIntervalId = window.setInterval(this.timer, this.interval);
}
```

Don't forget to change the interface accordingly:

```
interface JockeyState {
    interval: number;
    progress: number;
}

// Inside timer method
    if (this.state.progress === 100) {
        window.clearInterval(this.timerIntervalId);
        alert('you won!!');
    }
```

Also, it might be a good idea to clear the interval if your component is unmounted (but this depends on your app logic - you might want to leave the race running in background). Most of the time, though, you would create a separate service for that, so don't keep it in the component.

```
// how to clear on unmount
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerIntervalId);
}
```

**EDIT**:
Instead of using state the answer is using a private property in the component class now.

```
export class JockeyComponent extends React.Component<JockeyState, JockeyProps> {
    private timerIntervalId: number;


}
```

Comment: I get >Argument of type '{ intervalId: Timer; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State | ((prevState: Readonly<State>, props: Props) => State | Pick<State, "intervalId">) | Pick<...'.
  Type '{ intervalId: Timer; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<State, "intervalId">'.
    Types of property 'intervalId' are incompatible.
      Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: @colin_dev256 Change the `intervalId: number` member of the interface to `intervalId: Timer`

Comment: `[ts] Cannot find name 'Timer'` is the error I get.

Comment: @colin_dev256 revert back to `intervalId: number`, and instead of `setInterval` use `window.setInterval`.

Comment: `window` works :) however the `timer` continues even after clicking OK on the alert popup

Comment: @colin_dev256 what if you comment out the last line in your `timer()` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165646/discussion-between-colin-dev256-and-hlfrmn).

Answer (score 0):

Clear the interval you are setting.
Also when using prevState, it is always better to use the function pattern of `setState`

```js
class Jockey extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          interval: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
          progress: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.time = setInterval(this.timer, this.state.interval);
    }

    timer = () => {
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
          if(prevState.progress===100) {
            clearInterval(this.time);
            alert("Win");
            return {};  //No change in state
          } else {
            return {
              progress: prevState.progress+1
            }
          }
        });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.time);  //Clear timer when the timer unmounts
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App-lane">
                    <p>{this.state.progress}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Jockey />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your snippet works but from my end I get `[ts] Property 'time' does not exist on type 'Jockey'. Did you mean 'timer'` Might you know why?

Comment: You do not seem to be using typescript.

Comment: SO does not offer Typescript. So to make it run I had to remove the typescript annotations. You can add `this.time` an initial value and fix this, ti will still work in run time